# Raise index of refraction of spherical lens

Tags: optics, refraction, lenses

What happens to focal length and aperture of a spherical lens if you raise the index of refraction of the glass?

Answer (score 0):

You need the lens makers formula
$$\frac{1} {f} =\left(\frac{n_2} {n_1}-1\right)\left(\frac{1} {R_1} - \frac{1} {R_2}\right) . $$ With this you can work it out for yourself.